# How to pass data to another function | require('request')

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I get / pass the "body" from this function to a higher level (to another top level function)?

```
function f() {
    var request = require('request');
    request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://private-anon-147dec1d33-topupsapi.apiary-mock.com/operators/auto-detect/phone/+50936377111/country-code/HT?&includeBundles=true',
        headers: {
           'Accept': 'application/com.reloadly.topups-v1+json',
           'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik0wWXpRa'
        }
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        console.log('Status:', response.statusCode);
        console.log('Headers:', JSON.stringify(response.headers));
        console.log('Response:', body);
    });
}
```

Comment: instead of using console.log, make a function and call it with the parameter `body `

Comment: but its not to pass to top level....

Comment: If by `top level` you mean `Global` then all you need to do is to create a function within `Global` scope and call it with `body`.

Comment: please read this [ask]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function req(callback){
 var request = require('request');

request({
method: 'GET',
url: 'https://private-anon-147dec1d33-topupsapi.apiary-mock.com/operators/auto-detect/phone/+50936377111/country-code/HT?&includeBundles=true',
headers: {
'Accept': 'application/com.reloadly.topups-v1+json',
'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik0wWXpRa'
}}, function (error, response, body) {
    callback(body)
});
}

function callback(body){
   // Your higher function
}

req(callback);
```

One way is to pass body to a callback function.

Comment: Thanks. It is what i need!

Comment: is it possible to do with "async/await" ?